# How to predict the IP range of Fargate containers

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-fargate

We are currently using fargate to deploy our applicants and one of the services that we are using require us to enter a IP of the server that will be using the service. It does not have to be a single IP but can also be a range of ip like 192.1.x.x. How do I predict the IP range of fargate containers that will be created in my cluster so that I can enter the range of the IPs to the whitelist?

Comment: Can you put then service in private subnet behind a NAT gateway? This way you will have only one known public IP to whitelist.

Comment: @Marcin we would prefer not to incur any additional cost if possible. Is there any other way? Does Network Interface IP change once allocated?

Comment: A task in fargate requires `awsvpc` network mode. This creates one ENI (elastic network interface) for you. When fargate lunches a task, you will get some pubic IP for that. When you restart the task, you will get different IP. To mitigate this you could use Elastic IP which is static. You associated EIP with ENI and IP does not change. When you restart tasks, you associate same EIP with new ENI for new task. Otherwise, IP ranges of AWS are [known](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-ip-ranges.html). Thus can always use that.